# Psycopg2 connect throws Operational Error

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, psycopg2

I have a t2.micro ec2, in which I have scheduled 4 scripts to run daily. All of them throw the exact same error as mentioned below. Apparently, non of these throw any error when I run them manually - either locally or in the ec2. What can be the case?

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "script.py", line 17, in <module>
        connection = psycopg2.connect(user = USER2, password = PASSWORD2, host = HOST2, port = PORT2, database = DATABASE2)
      File "/home/ubuntu/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
        conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
    psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "..rds.aws.com" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Comment: If your question was answered please mark it as [solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: By any chance is the "..rds.aws.com" a somewhat dynamically-composed address, that is clearly failing? If this is the case, what's wrong is that whatever should fill the host and region part is not working... Could you please post the script?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the scripts using `cron`? Are you loading settings like `host` and `port` from a settings file? If yes, make sure your **working directory** is the correct one.

For cron I suggest using something like this for the command:

```
cd /home/ubuntu/project && python main.py
```

The `...rds.aws.com` part looks a bit odd ... shouldn't it be `...rds.amazonaws.com`?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Apparently, the working directory is right. I have copy-pasted the command used in the cron and it runs. The rds domain is simply a placeholder, it's indeed **..rds.amazonaws.com**

Comment: Can you share the cron configuration as well? Perhaps the user under which cron runs does not have some needed rights?